# Zimbra Rest API defining parameters in request URL

Tags: zimbra

In my Zimbra's queries for REST API, I want to get elements that match only with the name of contact :

```
http://zimbra.server.com/home/plinard/contacts?fmt=xml&query=(taichimaro)
```

But Zimbra returns every contact even if he find taichimaro as the function or phoneNumber, so how to tell him that I want to search on the lastName and not on all the fields ?

Thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to do it for a field :

Example : LastName

```
http://zimbra.server.com/home/plinard/contacts?fmt=xml&query=(FIELD[lastname]:taichimaro)
```

Example : Company

```
http://zimbra.server.com/home/plinard/contacts?fmt=xml&query=(FIELD[company]:stackoverflow)
```

Here is a link that shows all the attributes : 
Hope it can help everybody :)

[Zimbra Web Client Search Tips](http://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/Zimbra_Web_Client_Search_Tips)